# It is possible to conclude the basis function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I have to find the linear system corresponding to the approximate solution of an elliptic equation in 1D by using finite element method, the indications that give the exercise is that we have to find the function bases 
 $\left(\varphi_{j}\right)_{0 \leq j \leq N+1}$ defined as:
$$
\varphi_{j}(x)=\phi\left(\frac{x-x_{j}}{h}\right), 0 \leq j \leq N+1 \quad $$

with
$$
\phi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
(1+x)(1+2 x) & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
(1-x)(1-2 x) & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 & |x|>1
\end{array}\right.
$$
I construct a linear system using the previous function but when I execute a Matlab code I didn't get the result, after research, I found that our Discretization have to include the points $x_{j+1/2}$ and to add the following functions to the basis

$$ \quad \varphi_{j+1 / 2}(x)=\psi\left(\frac{x-x_{j+1 / 2}}{h}\right), 0 \leq j \leq N
$$

$$
\psi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1-4 x^{2} & |x| \leq 1 / 2 \\
0 & |x|>1 / 2  \\
\end{array}\right.
$$

My problem is that in the exercise there are no indications to previous functions $\varphi_{j+1/2}$ neither $\psi$, so I would like to know if there is a way to deduce the function $\varphi_{j+1/2}$ from $\varphi_{j}$

Thank you

Comment: First, the "finite element method" gives an **approximate** solution to a partial differential equation and there may be many equally accurate approximate solutions to the same problem.  Second, given any vector space there exist infinitely many different bases.  Finally, I don't know what the word "disctitisathon"!

Comment: Thank you, you're right and I corrected my post, I am a beginner in FEM. my question is specifically for the functions $(\varphi_{j})$ that we get from $\phi$. I was able to conclude the approximate solution corresponding to these functions but after the implementation, there is no result, but I read in a lecture note that another set of functions $(\varphi_{j+1/2})$  that we get from $(\psi)$ had to be added to the family $(\varphi_{j})$  and after we can approximate the solution.

Comment: So my question why the exercise asks to approximate the solution only by giving the set of functions $(\varphi_{j})$, is there a mistake or because we can calculate $(\varphi_{j+1/2})$ from $\phi$.

Comment: Not unless you can tell us WHAT that "1/2" means!

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear, the mesh vertices are $(x_{j})_{0 \leq j \leq N+1}$ and the midpoints $(x_{j+1 / 2})_{0 \leq j \leq N}=$
$\left(x_{j}+\frac{h}{2}\right)_{0 \leq j \leq N}$